# dplyr : filter a sequence of rows (in one column)

Tags: r, dplyr

A dummy data frame:

```
id_family<- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)
people<- c("male", "female", "male", "female", "male", "children") 

dataset <- data.frame(id_family, people)  
dataset
```

My results :

```
id_family   people
1           male            
1           female          
2           male            
2           female          
3           male            
3           children
```

What I want: filtering rows based on the "male and female" sequence

Expected result: filtering families 1 and 2

```
id_family   people
1           male            
1           female          
2           male            
2           female
```

I tried to use lag/lead dplyr's functions without success:

```
 dataset2 <- dataset %>%
    filter(people=="male", lead(people)=="female")
```

Comment: You're going to have to give us more information about what kind of data could possibly appear in `dataset` (could there be more than 2 people per family?) and what you want to pass the filter (the families that have at least one `male` and one `female`? The families that have exactly one `male` and one `female`?)

Comment: There is no column named `situation` in your data.

Comment: I always have 2 people per family (I made a filtering bebore)

Comment: The families that have exactly one male and one female

Comment: I a looking for "male - female" sequence and not "female -male" sequence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `all`

```
dataset %>%
      group_by(id_family) %>%
      filter(all(c("male", "female") %in% people))
# A tibble: 4 x 2
# Groups: id_family [2]
#  id_family people
#      <dbl> <fctr>
#1         1   male
#2         1 female
#3         2   male
#4         2 female
```

---

Or as per the OP's comments, if order is important then

```
dataset %>%
       group_by(id_family) %>% 
       filter(first(people)=="male", last(people) == "female", n()==2)
```