# dplyr calculating difference between values in first column based on sequence in second column

Tags: r, dplyr

```
age_member<- c(1975, 1980, 1979, 1985, 1993, 1998)
people<- c("male", "female", "male", "female", "male", "children") 

dataset <- data.frame(age_member, people)
```

My results:

```
age_member    people
1975      male          
1980    female          
1979    male            
1985    female          
1993    male            
1998    children
```

I am filtering this sequence **male(first), female(second)** acording to akrun' answer [dplyr : filter a sequence of rows (in one column)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43994756/dplyr-filter-a-sequence-of-rows-in-one-column)
**I am not keeping other sequences like male(first), children(second)**

What i want: creating a new column (`mutate`) base on ages differences.

```
dataset %>%
   filter(first(people)=="male", last(people) == "female", n()==2)
```

Expected result

```
age_member    people   ages_diff
1975    male            5
1980    female          NA
1979    male            6
1985    female          NA
```

What i tried :

```
dataset2 <-dataset %>%
   mutate(ifelse(first(people)=="male", last(people) == "female",n()==2), last(age)- first(age))
```

Comment: No problem, without that also, we can get the output, please check my solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try

```
library(dplyr)
dataset %>%
      group_by(ind = cumsum(people == "male")) %>% 
      filter(first(people)=="male", last(people) == "female", n()==2) %>% 
      mutate(ages_diff = c(diff(age_member), NA)) %>% 
      ungroup() %>%
      select(-ind)
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  age_member people ages_diff
#       <dbl> <fctr>     <dbl>
#1       1975   male         5
#2       1980 female        NA
#3       1979   male         6
#4       1985 female        NA
```