# How to filter a sequence of rows

Tags: r, dplyr

This should be an easy exercise for people more familiar with `dplyr`. Related questions are for example [dplyr : filter a sequence of rows (in one column)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43994756/dplyr-filter-a-sequence-of-rows-in-one-column), but I still can't make them work for my purposes.

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  speaker = c("B", "A", NA, "A", "B", NA, "B", "A", "A"),
  aoi = c("*A*", "BB", "*", "*CB", "*", "*C*", "*", "BC", "CB*")
)
```

I want to filter contiguous three-row sequences, where the first `speaker` value is not `NA`, the second `speaker` value is `NA`, and the third `speaker` value is not `NA` again. The result I'm looking for is this:

```
  speaker aoi
2       A  BB
3    <NA>   *
4       A *CB
5       B   *
6    <NA> *C*
7       B   *
```

I've tried the below code (in various guises) but can't get the result.

```
df %>%
  group_by(speaker) %>% 
  filter(lag(!is.na(speaker)) & is.na(speaker) & lead(!is.na(speaker)))
```

or:

```
df %>%
  group_by(speaker) %>% 
  filter(first(!is.na(speaker)) & nth(is.na(speaker),2) & nth(!is.na(speaker),3))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the index for the row which is in middle i.e `NA` and has `lead` and `lag` as not `NA`. Then select rows above and below it.

```
library(dplyr)

select_rows <- function(val) {
  inds <- which(is.na(val) & lag(!is.na(val)) & lead(!is.na(val)))  
  sort(unique(c(inds-1, inds, inds + 1)))
}

df %>% slice(select_rows(speaker))

#  speaker aoi
#1       A  BB
#2    <NA>   *
#3       A *CB
#4       B   *
#5    <NA> *C*
#6       B   *
```

Comment: Is `unique` really needed? Aren't the row indices automatically unique?

Comment: It depends on the data that you have. For the example that you have shared it is not needed but keeping it doesn't change the result.

Comment: Just one more question: how can I make sure that the three-row sequence always involves the same `speaker`, that is, for example, `A-NA-A`, or `B-NA-B` but **not** `A-NA-C`or `B-NA-A`, as is the case in the actual dataset?

Comment: You can create a new column, fill the `NA` values and use this as a `group_by` operation `df %>% mutate(grp = speaker) %>% tidyr::fill(grp) %>% group_by(grp) %>% slice(select_rows(speaker)) %>% ungroup %>% select(-grp)`